# Korean child was not accepted to college, what's next for her?

Tags: vocabulary, spoken-korean, korean-culture

My native Korean brother-in-law living in Seoul has what I would call a "star" child/pupil.  She won piano competitions, she is always studying, and she graduated #1 in her high school class (not an exaggeration, a literal #1 in her class).

I understand *in overview only* the **college entry exam(s)**. I do not know what my niece's score(s) turned out to be; but the entire family is shocked and dismayed because she did not make it into college.

So that I can have a base of understanding in order to have somewhat fluent Korean conversations with my Korean in-laws on this subject...

- **What are common vocabulary words and phrases surrounding the options for a child that does not make it into college via the entrance examination?**

Other questions that I'm sure I need to have a general understanding of to help the family cope with this situation include:

- What is the entrance exam or exam process vocabulary?
- Is there vocabulary, defined phraseology, common proverbs or idioms for failing to enter and then schooling overseas?
- Is there vocabulary, defined phraseology, common proverbs or idioms for going to get a job in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a student fails to gain entrance to college, he/she has several choices:

1. 재수 means "study again" literally,
2. 유학 means "go abroad to study", or
3. 취업/취직 means "take a job".

The Korean college entrance exam is called 수능, the abbreviation for [대학수학능력시험](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%8C%80%ED%95%99%EC%88%98%ED%95%99%EB%8A%A5%EB%A0%A5%EC%8B%9C%ED%97%98). This exam carries the same meaning as the [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT).

In Korea, taking a job is not an option for most of the students. They spend their high school years, entirely, preparing for the college entrance exam. It's definitely not a good situation, but competition is fierce here. So give her a word of comfort and share your elderly wisdom.

Comment: thanks - i expanded the full name of 대학수학능력시험 based on the wiki i found using your answer.  this is a big help, and i really appreciate the bulleted list of "what's next" options.  that helps me prepare for conversations with this vocabulary.  i also did not know the name of the korean college entrance exam, so having the full monty, as it were, is gold.